# Performance issue pandas 6 mil rows

Tags: pandas, performance, jupyter-notebook

need one help.

I am trying to concatenate two data frames. 1st has 58k rows, other 100. Want to concatenate in a way that each of 58k row has 100 rows from other df. So in total 5.8 mil rows.
Performance is very poor, takes 1 hr to do 10 pct. Any suggestions for improvement?
Here is code snippet.

```
def myfunc(vendors3,cust_loc):
cust_loc_vend = pd.DataFrame()
cust_loc_vend.empty
for i,row in cust_loc.iterrows():
    clear_output(wait=True)
    a= row.to_frame().T
    df= pd.concat([vendors3, a],axis=1, ignore_index=False)
    #cust_loc_vend = pd.concat([cust_loc_vend, df],axis=1, ignore_index=False)
    cust_loc_vend= cust_loc_vend.append(df)
    print('Current progress:',np.round(i/len(cust_loc)*100,2),'%')
return cust_loc_vend
```

For e.g. if  first DF has 5 rows and second has 100 rows

DF1 (sample 2 columns) 
[image]

[image]

I want a merged DF such that each row in DF 2 has All rows from DF1-
[image]

Comment: `Want to concatenate in a way that each of 58k row has 100 rows from other df.` What do you mean by this? Can you post a minimal produced example(to understand how dataframe looks like)?

Comment: Hi, yes. Have edited post to include additional details.

Answer (score 1):

Well all you are looking for is a join.But since there is no column column, what you can do is create a column which is similar in both the dataframes and then drop it eventually.

```
df['common'] = 1
df1['common'] = 1

df2 = pd.merge(df, df1, on=['common'],how='outer')

df = df.drop('tmp', axis=1)
```

where df and df1 are dataframes.

Comment: @prasoon shukla Please check if this helps.